# How to know which jQuery button was clicked in list context

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of stories on a page and each has several jQuery buttons for different actions.  When the button is clicked, I need to know what story it is was clicked for.

Currently I have each story wrapped in a `div` with an id of format `story_<story_id>` and then in the handler I traverse up and parse out the id.

```
<div id="story_1" class="story">
    Blah blah blah
    <input type="button" class="report-button" value="Report">
</div>

<div id="story_2" class="story">
    Blah blah blah
    <input type="button" class="report-button" value="Report">
</div>

<!-- more stories -->

<div id="story_9" class="story">
    Blah blah blah
    <input type="button" class="report-button" value="Report">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.report-button')
        .button()
        .click(function() {                
            var id_str = $(this).parents(".story").attr("id");
            var id = id_str.slice(6)
            alert(id);
        });
});
</script>
```

This works, but I wonder if there is a downside to this technique or if there is a better way.

I have also thought of:

- Using a form for each story with a hidden input with the id
- Putting the story id in the button id and parsing that, etc. `id="report_story_123"`

Is there a standard way to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it using data attributes as well, possibly removing the need for the parent IDs altogether:

```
<input type="button" class="report-button" data-id="1" value="Report">
```

Then get it using [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) on the `click` event like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('.report-button').button()
                     .click(function() {                
                       alert($(this).attr('data-id'));
                     });
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/nRnjz/)

Answer (score 2):

I would do it the way you currently are, but replace `.parents` with `.closest`.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```
<input type="button" class="report-button" name="story_9" value="Report">
```

and the javascript:

```
var id_str = $(this).attr("name");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's really a standard way of doing this. Your technique seems fine.

Now if you are going to submit this id to the server then probably using a form with a hidden field and a submit button is more adapted as you will no longer need to do any parsing or rely on order of DOM elements nesting to extract this id.