# Choose selectbox option by javascript by text

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Selecting an option by its text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541565/selecting-an-option-by-its-text)

Is there any way how to choose the option in selectbox **by the text label** of the option (**not the value**)?

```
<select id="form-mySelect" name="number">
    <option value="0">Zero</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>


$("#form-mySelect").val("One");
```

The example above doesn't work in jQuery 1.4.3. I've read somewhere, that in some lower version of jQuery selecting option by >text label< (**not by the value**) works.

Is there any way, how to simulate this behavior and make it functional in jQuery 1.4.3?

Comment: val is not a attribute of <option> it must be value

Comment: in jQuery v1.6.1 doing `$("#form-mySelect").val("One");` actually selects by the "one" text. Just want to mention.

Comment: @jimy: [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $('#form-mySelect").html() to get the label contents. So you could loop all options and compare the html() value with one given and then select the option.